# Gromacs 5.0.2 installation

Tags: software-installation

I am beginner on Gromacs, I tried to install 5.0.2 version and performed all steps, and I was almost confident that it had been installed successfully after command pdb2gmx.
But another day I opened the terminal and after mdrun -version command i faced this error:
gromacs version was 4.6.6!!!
what should I do?
thanks for your time

Comment: Hello. Can you include as much of the error as you can in your question?

Comment: Hi,I install gromacs 5.0.2 and there is no error, but when I close installation terminal and open new terminal and use "mdrun -version" command it shows that your gromacs version is 4.6.6!

Comment: How was `gromacs` installed? Can you include the procedure that you followed when you installed it? Because as far as I can see `mdrun` is different from gromacs, or is a single part of gromacs, so mdrun could have a different version number than gromacs. You might be able to see the install commands by taking a look at your `history` by doing something like `history > lets_see.txt` and then taking a look at when you installed gromacs.

Comment: Hi,In fact I used an installation Gromacs 5.0.2 tutorial on youtube, the installation had 3 main parts: 1) installing cmake which I download it from cmake site, 2) installing fftw, and 3) installing the Gromacs 5.0.2. you are right about mdrun, but even when I use the "pdb2gmx" comman the version 4.6.6. is being shown!thanks for your time

Comment: Can you update your original question by clicking on edit, and then putting the links that you followed in your question? Because if you compiled it from source, then it should be whichever version that is downloaded? This might be a dumb question, but are you sure that you downloaded gromacs 5.0.2?

Answer (score 0):

Its seems that your mdrun command is sourced to the gromacs-4.6.6 installations which is perhaps the preinstalled version in Ubuntu.  You need to uninstall (remove) the gromacs-4.6.6 version in Ubuntu using sudo apt-get remove gromacs*

See if this works